# WinError 5 Access is denied: 'C:\\Program Files (x86)

Tags: python, windows

I am trying to delete a temp file which a specific game uses with Python.
I am running CMD as admin and using code:

```
path = ""
if os.path.exists(path):
    os.remove(path)
```

This is giving me the error access denied likely because it is program files but any way around this?

Comment: Please post the [full error message with traceback](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341)

Comment: Yes, Program Files is one of the most restricted areas in Windows. I'd expect you to be able to access it as admin though.

Comment: Please provide error message.

Comment: @MarkRansom i ran as admin and same problem.

Comment: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\x\\AppData\\Local\\game_here\temp_files'

Comment: Aha, the story changes.  The location is actually somewhere in AppData\Local.  I can think of two reasons why it might fail.  First, the thing you're trying to delete is a directory not a file.  Second, it has the read-only attribute.

Comment: @MarkRansom I want to delete the actual folder named temp_files is that not possible? Or perhaps if not I could delete the temp files inside the folder

Comment: And if it has a read only attribute, how can I set it to remove the file

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments added to the question, it was misleading - you weren't trying to remove a file from `Program Files`, you were trying to remove a directory from `AppData\Local`.  There shouldn't be any problem with that, except that you're using `os.remove` to do it.  According to [the documentation:](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove)

> If path is a directory, an IsADirectoryError is raised. Use [rmdir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rmdir) to remove directories.

So the fix is simple:

```
os.rmdir(path)
```